# VBA MACRO EXCEL error Not Fetching Data into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

These line in my script throws the error.
and also am providing you corresponding html for the same so as to analyse on description attribute which has been given in html and also it doesn't accept html id attribute with dot (.)

Macro VBA-

```
searchtxt.Value = "Earth"

.document.forms(0).submit

Do While .Busy
DoEvents
Loop

Do While .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2") = "hgvgjjlj"

Set doc = .document
Set searchres = doc.getElementById("description").innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = searchres
```

HTML-

```
<textarea onblur="this.isFocused=false;" 
onkeydown="multiKeyDown(this);" 
onfocus="this.isFocused=true;" 
onchange="this.isFocused=false;multiModified(this)" 
data-charlimit="false" 
data-length="4000" 
spellcheck="true" 
name="u_incident_task.description" 
style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 356px;" 
id="u_incident_task.description" 
wrap="soft" specialtype="" class="form-control">Description:
Description xyz asdfghvb</textarea>
```

Comment: id is "u_incident_task.description", not "description"...  And use `.value` not `.innerText`

Comment: The following does not require `Set` ... `Set searchres = doc.getElementById("description").innerText`. You are assigning an value, not setting an object.

Comment: i have checked with the id is is not accepting that as well ....as there is a dot in it .

Comment: `doc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0).value` if there's only one textarea